# Form embedding Symfony2 data-prototype is Null

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to embed multiple file uploads within a subform in symfony2. 
I have an "idea" form which I want to have multiple "documents" form rendered in.
I have followed the documentation but come to a standstill when the data-prototype comes up as Null in the form. From my understanding the prototype is a string of html that renders the formtype. I have searched and it seems I am the only one to get this issue.
It must be something small but any help would be greatly appreciated.
my form type:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text')
       ->add('category', 'entity', 
        array('class' => 'AcmeIdeaBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'name', 
        ))
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('file','file')
        ->add('video')
        ->add('documents', 'collection', array('type' => new DocumentType,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true));
         }
```

document formtype builder:

```
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
        $builder
        ->add('file');
}
```

relevant twig file:

```
    {% block body %}
    <form action="{{ path('idea_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <ul class="docs" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }} " >
    {% for document in form.documents %}
    <li> {{ form_row(document.file) }} </li>
    {% endfor %}

    </ul>
```

if I hardcode some document objects in the controller they appear fine and editable but I need it to be dynamic.

javascript code :

```
    var collectionHolder = $('ul.docs');

    var $addDocumentLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_documents_link">Add a picture</a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addDocumentLink);

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    collectionHolder.find('li').each(function(){
    addDocumentFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });

    collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    $addDocumentLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    addDocumentForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
    });

    function addDocumentForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {

    var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');

    var newForm = prototype.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, collectionHolder.children().length);

    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);

    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    addDocumentFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
    }

    function addDocumentFormDeleteLink($docFormLi) {
    var $removeFormA = $('<a href= "#">remove?</a>');
    $docFormLi.append($removeFormA);

    $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $docFormLi.remove();
    });
    }
```

also this is my first time asking a question here so if i've done something wrong I apologize.

Comment: Which version of Symfony have you got? The form prototypes changed from version 2.0 to 2.1

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am running symfony 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

for some reason when I placed the code in the twig file

```
    <ul class="docs" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }} " >
    {% for document in form.documents %}
    <li> {{ form_row(document.file) }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

into a tabbed div ie

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="details"> 
    {{ form_row(form.video) }}
    <ul class="docs" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }} " >
    {% for document in form.documents %}
    <li> {{ form_row(document.path) }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}
    </div>
```

Now prototypes not null and all is well